# problem to compile after update angularCli

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Change the computer then install the latest angular version Cli, now my project gives me this error that I do not find information on the internet.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/fire/messaging/messaging.js 23:40
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (23:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         var _this = this;
|         if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
>             var requireMessaging = from(import('firebase/messaging'));
|             this.messaging = requireMessaging.pipe(map(function () { return _firebaseAppFactory(options, nameOrConfig); }), map(function (app) { return app.messaging(); }), runOutsideAngular(zone));
|             this.requestPermission = this.messaging.pipe(switchMap(function (messaging) { return messaging.requestPermission(); }), runOutsideAngular(zone));
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @Mikki yes, but not quite, just delete the references to `AngularFireMessageModule ` y I did not have the problem anymore, now when I need to use it I hope I do not have this problem

Comment: from which file I need to delete the references of `AngularFireMessageModule` ?

Answer (score 0):

Found some info in the [Angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/messaging/messaging.md#angularfiremessaging-is-not-compatible-with-the-angular-service-worker)

Looks like the issue is with the default Angular service worker not supporting the AngularFirebaseMessaging.

> **AngularFireMessaging is not compatible with the Angular Service Worker**
>
> If you are using the Angular Service Worker, you are not currently able to use AngularFireMessaging. If you'd like this feature please file an issue in either repository. Your alternatives are to use WorkboxJS or just simply use the Firebase Messaging Service Worker, which is detailed below

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependencies and solve one by one. Mainly focus on

- Downgrade `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version from `^0.13.9` to `^0.12.4`